# A condition on an argument used in multiple calls of a method: enforced by caller or by the method?

Tags: python, encapsulation, chain-of-responsibility

Let's assume I have an object ***a*** of a ***class A***. It has a method that needs an argument in form of another object of a particular type - but the argument should also be in particular state, because the operation performed by the method (let's say it's querying an external service, but it could be something else) requires it.

```
class A(object):
    def action(self, argument):

        return do_something(argument)
```

The first solution that comes to my mind is simple: the method should
enforce a condition on the input data. It should test it for required state and then either raise an exception or modify the state:

```
class A(object):
    def action(self, argument):
        if argument.state == False:
            raise Exception()

        return do_something(argument)

class A(object):
    def action(self, argument):
        if argument.state == False:
            argument.change_state()

        return do_something(argument)
```

However, the instance we are talking about is only one of many instances of the ***A***. All these instances should perform the same operation on input data: testing it for a particular state and then enforcing it, or just raising an exception. It seems they could use a shared instance of parameter whose required state is already enforced by an external caller, instance of ***class B***:

```
class B(object):
    def action(self, argument):
        argument.change_state()
        for a in self.instances_of_A:
            yield a.action(argument)
```

Because I think the operation performed by the method wouldn't be properly encapsulated without enforcing the required state of argument inside the method, I think it should be moved to the former caller. The object ***a*** and all other instances of ***class A*** would just provide data necessary for performing the operation.

```
class B(object):
    def action(self, argument):
        argument.change_state()
        for a in self.instances_of_A:
            yield  do_something(argument, a.data)
```

However, there is another problem: the operation returns a value that could be interpreted in a way related to instance of ***A*** to get another piece of data - and now it seems like the operation do_something should be encapsulated in a method of ***class A***.

How should I solve this problem? Should I simply keep the current design and make object **a** return data that could be used to interpret return code provided by the operation? Perhaps I should use chain of command pattern and modify ***class A*** to delegate the operation to other instances of A? What are the other ways I could handle it?

Comment: I would decorate A's method with a decorator function which would implement a particular constraint (or constraints) on the function arguments and then return a value as is

Comment: I haven't tried making my own decorator yet. Is using a decorator for storing modified value of an argument between many calls of the same method a good pattern?

Comment: Well, I'd like to ask about the part of your task related to "multiple instances of A and a shared argument". It's unclear if you're going to process the _same_ input date _simultaneosly_ , that is, the method `do_something` of one instance of the class A is invoked when another is in the middle of processing. What checks should be performed in this case?

Comment: Not simultaneusly, but consecutively. I'd like to modify the state of input data once (if it's necessary at all), and then use it for consecutive calls to action() method on differen instances of A. It seems right to me that it would be better not to repeat the modification of state of argument if it is intended to have the same result.